# how can I put jQuery code to jSX file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const END_POINT = 'http://localhost:3000'
export default class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            user: {
                id: '',
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                gender: '',
                birthday: '',
                email: '',
                profile: ''
            },
            signInModalIsOpen: false,
            signUpModalIsOpen: false,
            notificationModalIsOpen: false,
            makeQuestionModalIsOpen: false,
            ForgotPasswordModalIsOpen: false
            // isAuthenticated: props.isAuthenticated
        }

        this.findAuthenticationToken = this.findAuthenticationToken.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchUser()
    }

    findAuthenticationToken() {
        localStorage.getItem('sessionId') ?
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true }) :
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false })
    }

    openSignInModal() {
        this.setState({ signInModalIsOpen: true })
        const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
        body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    }
```

above code is coded by react.js, in this time, I wanna add jQuery code like below. 
If I add jQuery code to html file, I know type with the format like `<script></script>` and then, put the code to inside `<head></head>`
But in this time, I don't know how can I put jQuery code to jSX file.

```
$(function() {
    $('.navToggle').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.globalMenuSp').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.globalMenuSp').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Combing jQuery into your React code in this way is not advisable as it isn't very React-like, and would exist outside of React's lifecycle.  The above code should be able to be easily expressed with React.

Comment: thank you very much for fixing my code, and answering my question.

Comment: You are welcome-- happy coding and good luck!